# Image is breaking on a single page (could not load image)

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image which should be displayed on all the pages....it is working perfectly fine for all the pages except for a single page. On Inspect it shows could not load the image.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="images/uk.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help with your coding problem, you will need to actually **show** us your code. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your code, my guess is that it appears to be a **relative path** problem. The page in which you cannot load the image successfully is probably in a different folder to the pages where you **can** load the image successfully.

`<img src="images/uk.png">` is a **relative** link. According to that link usage, the file `uk.png` needs to be in the folder `images`, and the folder `images` needs to be in the **same folder** as the file you are trying to include the image on.

If your `images` folder is **not** a sibling of the file you are trying to include the image on, you have three options:

1. use **`../`** to navigate to the correct folder (`<img src="../images/uk.png">`)
2. use the **root-relative** `/` prefix (`<img src="/images/uk.png">`)
3. use an **absolute URL** (`<img src="http://www.example.com/images/uk.png">`)

For more information about relative paths, check out [**CSS Trick's article**](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/), **[Adobe's article](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/linking-navigation.html)**, or **[IfYouCodeItTheyWill's article](http://ifyoucodeittheywill.com/2009/03/absolute-relative-and-root-relative-urls/)**.

If you have ensured that your index file is indeed in the correct location, and your path is indeed correct, you may have a **caching** problem. Try holding `SHIFT` while clicking the `refresh` icon, and see if that works. If not, you can bring up your console with `F12` to further debug the problem.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Glad to hear this solution appears to have worked for you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)